# How to unit test void method of web api controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, controller, integration-testing

I have a void method in controller which insert data to local database. How can i do a integration test on that method.

I have tried this so far and don't know what to add in assert.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessTransactions()
    {
        // Arrange
        _transactionController = new TransactionController(_transactionService, _mService);

        // Act
        _transactionController.ProcessTransactions;

        // Assert
    }
```

Comment: You need to check that Act is completed as expected. You asking about how people would access inner state to check? If that is your question, the answer is - Inversion of Control and service location.

Comment: can i check if post method returns any error without updating controller method?

Comment: Of course, your method should throw exception if that happens. Then test would automatically fail and you don't need to assert anything.

Comment: I am curious why the web api controller action is void and not returning `IHttpActionResult` or `HttpResponseMessage` like in some of your previous examples

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, depending on what you want to test and how deeply you want to test it.

1. If you want to check your controller interaction with it's dependencies, you can use a mock (e.g. mock your `_transactionService`) and assert what methods were called on the mock, with what parameters, etc. I personally do **not** recommend this type of tests though. They make your code very refactoring-resistant. It doesn't really test what your app does, but rather **how** your app does it, which makes little sense to me.
2. You can run your tests on the real implementations of your classes (no mocks). Then you should focus on verifying the system state (e.g. what's in the database) after the tested method execution. This kind of tests worked better for me, but they require you to setup a database first with some seed data, which could be a big hassle in a large system. These test run slowly, due to database communication and especially due to the need of arranging a database state beforehand.
3. You can also skip the test of the controller, or do it very sketchily and focus on testing your domain logic. It's still good to throw a few simple tests just to verify whether your controllers work at all.

There's no definite answer to this question. It all "depends", but I hope I threw some light on possibilities.